# Unable to store data in SQL Server from C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
private void button_Pass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JAYI-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db-ub;Integrated Security=True");
    con1.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Insert into Visitors(Id,Visitor_Name,Organisation_Name,Phone_No,No_Person,To_whom,Purpose,Color_Code,Day_In,Time_In,Image) values (@id,@vname,@org,@phn,@nop,@whom,@prps,@ccd,@dI,@tI,@img)");
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textBox_Id.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vname", textBox_NameV.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@org", textBox_Org.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phn", textBox_Phn.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nop", numericUpDown_Person.Value.ToString());
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@whom", comboBox_TOWHOM.SelectedItem.ToString());
    string prps;
    if(radioButton_OFFICIAL.Checked) 
    {
        prps = "Official";
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prps", prps);
    } else if(radioButton_PERSONAL.Checked) 
    {
        prps = "Personal";
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prps", prps);
    }
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ccd", comboBox_color.SelectedItem.ToString());
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dI", textBox_Dayin.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tI", textBox_timeR.Text);
    Image img = pictureBox_UB.Image;
    byte[] arr;
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    arr = (byte[]) converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof (byte[]));
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", img);
    MessageBox.Show("Record has been inserted");
    con1.Close();
}
```

I have a table in a SQL Server database with columns

```
Id, Visitor_Name, Organisation_Name, Phone_No, 
No_Person, To_whom, Purpose, Color_Code, 
Day_In, Time_In, Day_Out, Time_Out, Image
```

Now I want to insert values of (`Id, Visitor_Name, Organisation_Name, Phone_No, No_Person, To_whom, Purpose, Color_Code, Day_In, Time_In, Image`) into database.

I wrote this code in C# shown above, but it's working fine but not storing any data to SQL Server database. Please help.

Comment: You're never *executing* the command. Use `cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()`. Also, *please* make an effort to format your code before you post. It's horribly hard to read with no indentation.

Answer (score 3):

Two problems here:

1. You are not adding your connection to your command, use the constructor which takes a [command string and a connection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/877h0y3a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to initialise like:

   ```
   new SqlCommand("Insert into Visitors(Id,Visitor_Name,Organisation_Name,Phone_No,No_Person,To_whom,Purpose,Color_Code,Day_In,Time_In,Image) values (@id, @vname, @org, @phn, @nop, @whom, @prps, @ccd, @dI, @tI, @img)", con1);
   ```
2. You are not executing your command! Add:

   ```
   cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
   ```

before `MessageBox.Show`

Answer (score 2):

i think you should add cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery() before MessageBox.Show("Record has been inserted");

Because you have not executed your sqlcommand yet.

Comment: After writing cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery() before MessageBox.Show("Record has been inserted"); it is giving the error " Connection has not been initialized.

Comment: add sql connection in sql command object like sqlcommand("command string",connnection object)